# Docker logs are not buffered correctly

Tags: docker, logging, splunk

I have a Docker application which push Docker logs to Splunk

The logs appears like this:

```
{
  "log": "json here",
  "stream": "stdout",
  "time": "time here"
}
```

The problem is that when Docker produces logs very fast, Splunk is not able to parse it and then all the logs will appear like raw in Splunk.

Do you have any idea which parameter might I tune?

Comment: How is your application pushing logs to splunk?

Comment: Yes sorry to not mention. json-file

Comment: What about using the [splunk logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/splunk/)?

Comment: I can't. they are not reliable. I can't depend by Splunk. if Splunk goes down or ti doesn't work then the app can't work

Comment: @Mazzy good point, this is exactly what we are solving with our solution for monitoring docker https://www.outcoldsolutions.com - we built it on top of native JSON logs, which makes it reliable. On this page https://www.outcoldsolutions.com/docs/collectorfordocker/ you can find a comparison of our solution with Splunk Logging Driver. 
Btw, I am original author of Splunk Logging Driver and Splunk Docker Images.